# API data display - flutter card widget

Tags: api, flutter, dart

Get API connection is successful. but I have no idea how to map data.. how is connect snapshot.data,
I want to display data in a Stack widget.

https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/networking/fetch-data

I learned this from the association with this source

```
Future<News> fetchNews() async {
  final response =
  await http.get('#url');
  print(response.body);

  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    return News.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body));
  } else {
    throw Exception('Failed to load news');
  }
}

class News {
  final String title;
  final String description;
  final String image;

  News({this.title, this.description, this.image});

  factory News.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return News(
      title: json['title'],
      description: json['description'],
      image: json['image'],
    );
  }
}

  Widget _buildPage(BuildContext context, int direction) {
    Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return SafeArea(
      child: FutureBuilder<News>(
        future: futureNews,
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            return newsCard(snapshot.data);
          } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
            return Text("${snapshot.error}");
          }
          return CircularProgressIndicator();
      },
    ),
    );
  }

  Widget newsCard(size){
    return Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
        Container(
          child: Image.network(
              image,
              fit: BoxFit.cover
          ),
          height: size.height/2.0,
        ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
```

Comment: can you show your future? are you getting the data in json? are you decoding the data after? From your code it seems like your News object is being used to get the height? is that correct? and where is the image variable being declared?

Comment: ok.. thank you for your response. I updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is a bit messy and it doesn't make much sense. It seems obvious that the data is not getting displayed because you're passing your `News` object to your `newsCard` function, but the parameter seems to be expecting `Size`. I also don't know where are you getting the `image` property from since it doesn't seem to be declared anywhere in the code.

Doing some changes to your code, a minimal working function that returns your widget would look like this:

```
Widget _buildPage(BuildContext context, int direction) {
    Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return SafeArea(
      child: FutureBuilder<News>(
        future: futureNews,
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            return newsCard(snapshot.data, size);
          } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
            return Text("${snapshot.error}");
          }
          return CircularProgressIndicator();
      },
    ),
    );
  }

  Widget newsCard(News news, Size size){
    return Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
        Container(
          child: Image.network(
              news.image,
              fit: BoxFit.cover
          ),
          height: size.height/2.0,
        ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
```

**UPDATE**

If you're getting the error you mentioned bellow, is likely that your response from the get request is a list of `News` and not just one `News` object, therefore you'll have to change this:

```
return News.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body));
```

To this:

```
return jsonDecode(response.body).map<News>((object) => News.fromJson(object)).toList();
```

The return type of `fetchNews()` should be `Future<List<News>>` instead of `Future<News>`

Comment: I have an error. "Error: List<dynamic> is not a subtype of type Map<String, dynamic> "

Comment: is your response a list?

Comment: I added these changes.. but I had anther error in FutureBuilder.. " future: futureNews, " part had the error and not suggest any error code.

Comment: lib/widgets/news.dart:59:17: Error: The argument type 'Future<List<News>>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Future<News>'.
 - 'Future' is from 'dart:async'.
 - 'List' is from 'dart:core'.
 - 'News' is from 'package:openmic_mobile/widgets/news.dart' ('lib/widgets/news.dart').
        future: futureNews,

Comment: That's because you have marked the FutureBuilder to expect a Future<News>. You need to also add the expected type to List<News> to the FutureBuilder.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226977/discussion-between-jose-georges-and-arosha).